# What do you call a Android page? Activity or View or ? Genuinely need clarification

Tags: android

I always get this these two confused with together. I just wanted to know the difference I'm new to android development and I'm learning as I go along.

Comment: Someone Explain the difference and what you call a Android page. moving from one page to another

Answer (score 1):

It is called Activity. But there can be Fragments within a activity. But it can be somthing else, depending on what you call a Android page to be!

And a View is the class on which all the UI components are build!

There  is nothing to be confused at!

You head over to https://developer.android.com/training/index.html
It is the best to get started!

There are plenty of resources just to let you clear your doubts, you should try making a google search before posting a query here.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll take the advice given and research and start developing to help get myself familiarized with android dev

Comment: Good! Look for some starter projects after you know the very basics. Build them. Getting hands-on experience is always a better way to learn! and Choose this as the accepted answer if this helped! :)

Comment: `View` is not the superclass of `Activity`, nor of `Fragment`.

Comment: @Mike M. Yeah! My bad, checked it now! Thanks for the clarification! :)